# Gitlab Pages and cookies

Tags: gitlab-pages

I am thinking about hosting my static website using gitlab pages.

The website is completely static, no dynamic contents (besides me updating it from time to time).

Now I am wondering: Since I am in the EU, I have to add a cookie Banner if applicable. Looking at my websites request headers, I can see the following cookie:

```
gitlab-pages=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_UbWI8oEm_Rl-pfIPpynNRNoM1U=
```

I am wondering:

- What does this cookie do?
- Can I disable it somehow?
- If I cannot disable it, do I have to make a cookie banner?

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem? I am at the same point right now

Comment: yes, sorry for not answering my own question earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookie is actually only send when one is logged into GitLab and contains the authorization information.
To remove it:

- make the page public
- if that is not enough, also log out of GitLab